# Android App "failed to install" on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I've been testing my app on a tab emulator (runs just fine), but when attempting to run the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 today, I am running into a "failed to install" error. When I run, I am given the option for the device, I select it and then receive:

```
[2014-02-19 09:46:51 - Ops_Suite_Android] Failed to install Ops_Suite_Android.apk on device '4300f4b4b0979017': timeout
[2014-02-19 09:46:51 - Ops_Suite_Android] Launch canceled!
```

I increased the connection timeout to 10 seconds and still no luck. Immediately proceeding the timeout, on secondary run i am given :

```
[2014-02-19 09:46:57 - Ops_Suite_Android] Failed to install Ops_Suite_Android.apk on device '4300f4b4b0979017': EOF
[2014-02-19 09:46:57 - Ops_Suite_Android] java.io.IOException: EOF
[2014-02-19 09:46:57 - Ops_Suite_Android] Launch canceled!
```

After this attempt, the device shows offline for any further attempts. I pull out the USB and reconnect, only to go through the same errors every time. Any ideas?

By the way, I am noticing that the connection itself seems to go out after the second attempt and sometimes will reconnect, bringing up the device options all over again on my comp (like opening folders or opening pictures). I also notice that plugging in results in no charge to the tab, i get the charge symbol on the device with a big red x through it. Could this problem be related to connection issues or driver issues or something else?

Comment: My suspicion is that your USB cable is the evil bastard!

Comment: Oh, and I've tried with 2 USB cables. Both which charge the device when plugged in to an outlet rather than my comp.

Comment: It should be about your Target. I was developing using Galaxy Tab 10.1 myself a month ago. It was Android 4.0.4, my target was 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is generally caused when the device loses communication during an install. Try the following.

1. Clean your project. (Delete `/bin/` and rebuild all.
2. Different USB Cable
3. Restart device.
4. Restart IDE and ADB Daemon (Reboot)

If the issue persists, try deleting your creently installed ADB driver, and use the one provided in the Android `sdk-addons` pack.

Comment: Could it be that when trying to update the drivers for the tab, i literally found zero? I know that Samsung has a reputation for all driver dls and updates need to come directly from their site. I was only able to find SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip which happened to work from what it seems. Nothing for their tablet

Comment: i will attempt to find another cable to see if that resolves my issue.

Comment: Generally, you do not need any device specific drivers for debugging, as ADB is part of the Android System, and is universal across phones. Inside of your SDK installation, you have the ADB driver. `android-sdk/extras/google/usb_driver/`. If none of the above steps work, try reinstalling this driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Samsung S4.  Tried everything suggested. plus more..  I ended up rebooting my osx machine and it started working again.